# Setting value using UseState hook adds a "tableData" object to data fetched from API

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I am fetching data from a flask API using Axios, then using the useState hook to use that data to build a table. The error I'm encountering is that after I use the setValue function to update the state, an extra "tableData:{id:0}" object is added to the JSON object the API returning, and it seems to happen after the setValue function is called.

I have already tried to use `delete values.key.tableData` when I was only dealing with single objects, but now that I have an array of objects it doesn't work anymore, and I don't understand why this key is even added in the first place.

I get an "undefined" error when I don't use the initial state like I did below.

The console shows the original string (not parsed yet) when i log the API's original response, but shows this when I log the state:
`​
0: Object { Email: "", tableData: {…} }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
​`

How do I keep the "tableData" key from being added to the response? Is there an issue with the way I'm using the hook?

The relevant parts of the code are down here:

```
      React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api",{params: { start: selectedstartDate, end: selectedendDate}}).then((response)=>{  
      console.log(response.data.details);
      setValues(response.data.details);
      console.log(values);

    }, []);
```

Comment: could you show the response you get from the server please ?

Comment: This is what i get from console.log(response.data.details) (I'll just put in the first couple values since it's a long string:

[{"Email":"ala","Program":"","Location":"","Manager":"Not Found","Days of Absence":1},{"Email":"alex","Program":"L","Location":"B","Manager":"K T","Days of Absence":3}]

It's a JSON formatted array of objects, which I want to parse afterwards since the API returns it as a string.

Comment: Are you use mapping method in setValues function?

Comment: I'm not, since the extra key gets added to the initial state too even before I parse the response object. I should not have to use a mapping method since the response is already a string representation of an array of objects and I just want to parse it.

Comment: Can you share inside of setValues function?

Comment: It's the default function created by useState, I'm not defining it myself.

Comment: After some more tests, it seems that using the MaterialTable package is probably the source of the issue. Thing is, I don't understand how it can affect the state in this way?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the way MaterialTable behaves, the issue was created by it mutating whatever is passed as data, so in this case my state variable, and adding that extra key to render the table. To solve this, I added a second state variable which is a copy of the first one, that I only use for the table data prop, and kept using the original values for everything else.